# Progress bar not updating in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm facing the following problem: My progressBar is not updating in JavaFx.

I have written the following code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
static final int max = 1000000;

Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
    }
};
@FXML
public AnchorPane root;
@FXML
public ProgressBar progressWater;
@FXML
public ProgressBar levelGas;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    if (!Main.isSplashLoaded) {


        loadSplashScreen();

    }

}

private void loadSplashScreen() {
    try {
        Main.isSplashLoaded = true;

        StackPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(("SplashFXML.fxml")));
        root.getChildren().setAll(pane);


        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), pane);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);

        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), pane);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0);
        fadeOut.setCycleCount(1);

        fadeIn.play();

        fadeIn.setOnFinished((e) -> {
            fadeOut.play();



        });

        fadeOut.setOnFinished((e) -> {
                  AnchorPane paneMain;
            try {
                paneMain = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        root.getChildren().setAll(paneMain);
        paneMain.setOpacity(0);

        FadeTransition fadeInmain = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), paneMain);
        fadeInmain.setFromValue(0);
        fadeInmain.setToValue(1);
            fadeInmain.play();
            fadeInmain.setOnFinished((ex)-> {
              //  progressWater.setProgress(0.5);
                double maxlev = progressWater.getPrefWidth();
                progressWater.progressProperty().bind(fadeInmain.fromValueProperty());
  /**
    * Action goes here
    */

                new Thread(){
                    public void run() {
                        for (double i = 0.0; i < maxlev; i++){
                            final double step = i;
                            Platform.runLater(() ->

                                    progressWater.setProgress( step / 10 ));
                            System.out.printf("Complete: %02.2f%n", step /10);

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

                progressWater.progressProperty().unbind();

    /**
      * Action ends here
      */
            });

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

When executing the code, the thread updates, and it prints in the console the completion, however, the progressWater bar does not update in the UI.
Below is my FXML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

  <AnchorPane id="MainPane" fx:id="root" prefHeight="322.0"        prefWidth="232.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.FXMLDocumentController">

    <children>

        <ImageView fitHeight="322.0" fitWidth="232.0" pickOnBounds="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@background.jpg" />
         </image>

      </ImageView>
        <ProgressBar fx:id="progressWater" layoutX="-80.0" layoutY="170.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="5.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="1.0" rotate="90.0">
            <effect>
                <GaussianBlur radius="2.0" />
            </effect>

        </ProgressBar>
        <ProgressBar fx:id="levelGas" layoutX="113.0" layoutY="170.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="5.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" rotate="90.0">
            <effect>
                <GaussianBlur radius="2.0" />
            </effect>
        </ProgressBar>

    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see a `progressWater.progressProperty().unbind();` right after the task starts. Did not track through the logic of the entire code though. Too much of it. Like the answer below, binding the progress to a value of an animation is something I have never seen anyone do before.

Comment: This is my logic, however, if it cannot be done, can you please help me with this, as I am a complete newbie at javafx. Thank you!

Comment: [JavaFX concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) may explain how it does work.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me immediately that you are before running the thread that spins and updates the progress..

```
                progressWater.progressProperty().bind(fadeInmain.fromValueProperty());
```

You're binding the progress property to something else entirely that you aren't updating seemingly, have you tried removing this binding to allow the property to float on its own and not be tied to the propagating events from the fadein property?